# What is with the decrepit body in the French Chateau?

Tags: uncharted-3

At one point during the French Chateau chapter, Nate & Sully come across a body of one of Talbot's men that is heavily decayed. Sully questions how it was possible for the body to be so decayed as Talbot and his men "just got there".

While I was hoping this would be explained as the game went on, no references were ever made back to it.

Comment: That would be one of many unexplained things in this game.

Comment: Isn't that in the same chateau where you encounter the spiders the first time? Since they're so similar to the scarabs in "The Mummy", I assumed they inflicted the same damage to their victims (even though it's never explicitly shown in-game)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Uncharted Wiki,](http://uncharted.wikia.com/wiki/Uncharted_Wiki) Talbot's man was killed by the [spiders](http://uncharted.wikia.com/wiki/Spiders). As there is no direct reference to the cause of death in the game, I think you're just supposed to infer it.

Answer (score -3):

It was kind of creepy for me too. If you take the time to look after "Harris" dies from spiders, his body is all decayed and creepy. Just like the Agent seen before you go in that hole leading to the Floor Puzzle.